# Select '('abc','def','ghi')' as values from dual not working

Tags: sql, string, oracle, single-quotes

I tried to run the query in Oracle:

```
Select '('abc','def','ghi')' as values from dual
```

But I receive the error

> ORA-00923 "FROM keyword not found where expected

As output I would like to have:

```
Values
-------------
('abc','def','ghi')
```

Can you please explain why is not working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape `'`, also values is reserved which can be used in update statements, please try

```
SELECT '(''abc'',''def'',''ghi'')' AS VAL FROM DUAL
```

output

```
('abc','def','ghi')
```